# Laravel task scheduling- making multiple commands and tasks

Tags: cron, laravel-5.3

I am trying to make 2 artisan commands that would each do a different task that should also be scheduled to do their tasks each day.
So far, I have set it up like this:

I have created a FolderImport class in the Console/Commands directory:

```
class FolderImport extends Command
{

  protected $signature = 'import:folders';

  /**
  * The console command description.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $description = 'Imports folders';

  /**
  * Create a new command instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct(ImportController $folders)
  {
      parent::__construct();

      $this->folders = $folders;
  }

  /**
  * Execute the console command.
  *
  * @return mixed
  */
  public function handle()
  {
      $this->folders->scheduledImport();
  }
```

}

And the ContentImport class:

```
class ContentImport extends Command
{
  protected $signature = 'import:content';

  /**
  * The console command description.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $description = 'Imports content';

  /**
  * Create a new command instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct(ImportController $content)
  {
      parent::__construct();

      $this->content = $content;
  }

  /**
  * Execute the console command.
  *
  * @return mixed
  */
  public function handle()
  {
      $this->content->scheduledImport();
  }
}
```

And then in the Kernel file I have added them like this:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\ContentImport::class,
        Commands\FolderImport::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('import:content')
            ->withoutOverlapping();

        $schedule->command('import:folders')
            ->withoutOverlapping();

        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController@all')
            ->dailyAt('00:00');

        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController@folder')
            ->dailyAt('00:00');
    }
}
```

How can I connect the `import:folders` command with the call to `ImportController@folder` and the command `import:content` to the call to `ImportController@all`?